# How mock RestTemplate.exchange()?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mocking, mockito

I have tried almost everything but I keep getting a `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem` when trying to mock `RestTemplate.exchange`

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
@Test
    void headerTest() {
    var request = getRequest();

    when(restTemplate.exchange(
            ArgumentMatchers.any(),
            ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
            ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,Object>>>any(),
            ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any())
    )
            .thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok("{\"access_token\":\"token\"}"));

    client.getResponse(request,
            "HI");

    assertEquals(1,request.hashCode());
}
```

I have tried everything but I keep getting the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'exchange' method:
    restTemplate.exchange(
    null,
    POST,
    <{grant_type=[client_credentials]},[AUTHORIZATION:"Basic ", Content-Type:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]>,
    class java.lang.String
);
    -> at com.client.Client.getToken(WeightedAverageCostClient.java:148)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. restTemplate.exchange(
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
);
```

Using `lenient()` I am getting a response of NULL.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
when(restTemplate.exchange(
                ArgumentMatchers.any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>>any(),
                ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any(),
                (Object) any())
        )
                .thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok("{\"access_token\":\"token\"}"));
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason to mock the `restTemplate` itself?
The generic recommendation is to avoid the `restTemplate` invocation at all by using fake services.

In case of the invocation is absolutely mandatory the in-memory stub solution like [mock-server](https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/running_mock_server.html) could be used during the tests.